# Reverse ordering in Mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a data in similar faashion as given in the dwl script variable.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = { "2022-10-19T10:59:00.000Z":[{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-17T10:59:00.000Z": [{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-18T10:59:00.000Z": [{"kio":"spotage"}] 
            }
---
test  orderBy $$
```

Need to sort by dateformat in ASC order. Getting the below response which is the default ordering `DSC`. Wanting to reverse it  `ASC`. Tried `-$$` and also `[-1 to 0]` and tried formatting as LocalDateTime check to see if it is working.

```
    {
  "2022-10-17T10:59:00.000Z": [
    {
      "kio": "spotage"
    }
  ],
  "2022-10-18T10:59:00.000Z": [
    {
      "kio": "spotage"
    }
  ],
  "2022-10-19T10:59:00.000Z": [
    {
      "kio": "spotage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expecting response as below

```
{
    "2022-10-19T10:59:00.000Z": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ],
    "2022-10-18T10:59:00.000Z": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ],
    "2022-10-17T10:59:00.000Z": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if the question is not clear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `$$` is `Key`. Therefore you can not do -$$ directly.
You need to convert the keys to String and then to DateTime so that it can properly sort it properly.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = { "2022-10-19T10:59:00.000Z":[{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-17T10:59:00.000Z": [{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-18T10:59:00.000Z": [{"kio":"spotage"}] 
            }
---
test orderBy -($$ as String as DateTime)
```

Comment: On the other scenario instead of DateTime, I'm having only Date (To orderBy). If I change the above to script to orderBy -($$ as String as Date). It is not working as it is expecting a Number because of `-`. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to give the format of a Date or DateTime if is it not in ISO format. Refer this  answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74268170/10946202

Comment: Thanks. I tried this script orderBy -($$ as String as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}), it is not like the format though as `-` expects a number.

Comment: Also tried other ways. Either it complains - or date format. Thoughts?

Comment: @star, in the case of Date, you can just remove the dashes and take that as the number to then add the minus.