# Reverse ordering in Mule4 using Date field

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I wanted to do reverse ordering using Date field from highest to lowest (DSC). This question is similar to the below link [Reverse ordering in Mule4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298930/reverse-ordering-in-mule4/74299007#74299007). Thought small tweaks would make the fix. Tried various ways.Not working. When I try to format date it says the key cant be formatted to date or it complains about `-`. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = { "2022-10-19":[{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-17": [{"kio":"spotage"}] ,
            "2022-10-18": [{"kio":"spotage"}] 
            }
---
test orderBy -($$ as String as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

)

Expected Response:

```
{
    "2022-10-19": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ],
    "2022-10-18": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ],
    "2022-10-17": [
        {
            "kio": "spotage"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should add the errors to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orderBy() function seems to be expecting a number to be able to do reverse sorting. A Date [can not be converted directly to a number in DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-types-coercion). However the date format 'yyyyMMdd' can be converted to a number that can directly sorted.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test =  { 
                "2022-10-18":[{"kio":"spotage"}],
                "2022-10-17": [{"kio":"spotage"}],
                "2022-10-19": [{"kio":"spotage"}] 
            }
---
test orderBy -($$ as String as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} as String {format: "yyyyMMdd"} as Number)
```

I modified the input to show that the script actually orders the output.

Comment: I tried all the possible way for making as Date format and converted as Number- Didnt work. Haven't know {format: "yyyyMMdd"} do. Learning for me. Thanks for explaining in details.@Aled. As always appreciate it.

Comment: You can use Java date time pattern characters in DataWeave.